# insert static valus from select box laravel

Tags: laravel-5

im new to laravel when i try to insert data from static select option to database i get "Field 'city' doesn't have a default value" email,username ,password are good
i did try previous solutions on stack overflow but nothing works
thank  you in advance

```php
// this is my model
class Job_Seeker extends Model
{
    protected $guard='job_seeker';
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password','city','categories'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
    protected $casts = ['email_verified_at' => 'datetime'];
    public $table = "job_seekers";
}
```

```php
// this is register_controller
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|unique:job_seekers',
        'password'=>'min:5|required',
    ]);    

    $job_seeker = new Job_seeker;
    $job_seeker ->name = $request->name;
    $job_seeker ->email = $request->email;
    $job_seeker ->city = $request->city;
    $job_seeker ->categories = $request->categories;
    $job_seeker ->password = Hash::make($request->password);
    $job_seeker ->save();
}
```

```xml
// this is  form 
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('job_seeker.register') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="wrap">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="login-input" name="username">
        <input type="email"placeholder="email" class="login-input" name="email">
        <input type="password"placeholder="Password" class="login-input" name="password">
        <input type="password"placeholder="confirm Password" class="login-input" name="password_confirmation">
        <select name="city"  id="city" class="grid" required="required">
            <option value="" disabled selected> city</option>
            <option value="chicago">Chicago</option>
            <option value="losangeles">Los Angeles</option>
            <option value="seattle">Seattle</option>
            <option value="dallas">Dallas</option>
            <option value="boston">Boston</option>
            <option value="sanfran">San Francisco</option>
        </select>
        <select name="categories"  id="categories" class="grid">
            <option value="" disabled selected> catégories</option>
            <option value="web design">web design</option>
            <option value="infor">inforgraphie</option>
            <option value="tele">télecomunication</option>
            <option value="inf">infirmiére</option>
            <option value="cpmta">comptabilité</option>
            <option value="agri">agriculture</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="login-input" >
        <div class="separator">
            <span class="divider">or</span>
            <span class="sep"></span>  
        </div>
        <div class="social-login">
            <p class="social-button">
                <a class="facebook-before"><span class="fontawesome-facebook"></span></a>
                <button class="facebook">login Using Facbook</button>
            </p>
            <p class="social-button">
                <a class="twitter-before"><span class="fontawesome-twitter"></span></a>
                <button class="twitter">login Using Twitter</button>
            </p>
        </div> 
    </div>
</form>
```

there is no need for web routes file i thinq is good

Comment: Can you please provide output of `dd($request->all());` from `store()` function here?

Comment: balkal i try it but the same error shown

Comment: In `dd($request->all())`; what value it shows against 'city' parameter? The city column in your table is possibly set to `not null` and somehow a blank value of the city is being sent to the insert query. Please check if `required` validation is working in browser and if the server is receiving a non-blank value of city field.